# VS.Net Community VS Express

Tags: visual-studio

mWhat is the Diffrence between the newly VS.NET community edition to the VS.NET express editions in the past?
Is the express edition will be now only for web development and the community for everything?
Is it just for VS.NET 2013?

Answer (score 0):

VS express was free but **limited feature** compared to all VS can do.

Now Visual studio is free (*for individual developer not companies with a lot of developers*) so community edition **does not limit content** visual studio offers.

[microsoft VS link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx).

Comment: No it started with 2013 and it is related to Microsoft choice to make dotnet opened. You can even install and use VS 2015 preview right now.

Answer (score 0):

Community edition is the full fledged software, but you can't use it on enterprise (>5 users)

On the other hand, Express editions can be used in enterprise environments, but does not let you use plugins.

So in the end, as far as I can tell the choice is between plugins and enterprise.